# Delphi: what is wrong with my SQL query not returning any results

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I was trying to prevent SQL injection in my Delphi application by securing user inputs using the following query:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var userNameID : string;
begin
     userNameID := edit1.Text;
     with adoquery1 do
      begin
        sql.Clear;
        sql.Add('select * from users where id = :'''+userNameID+''';');
        Open;
      end;
end;
```

but it's not returning any results.

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code please?

Comment: It's much better to use parameters in your queries as opposed to strings. I think that the problem is the semicolon before the username.

Comment: SQL injection issues aside, the above code is probably not working because of the colon which should be removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything to prevent SQL injection, because you're still directly concatenating text to the query. Your SQL syntax is also invalid.

Something like this will work:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from users where id = :ID');
  AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').AsString := edit1.Text;
  AdoQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: @DJMixRhymez This is more than a "tip", this is *the* answer to your question. You should mark this as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left.

Comment: sorry i'm new here, i still don't know how this website works, but thank you :)